# Jargon for running app on 2 servers where 1 server is 1 release behind

Tags: release-management

I came up with the idea to run 2 different servers with both of them having the same app, but one is just 1 release behind.

Why would I want to do this?

Sometimes one of of our releases is faulty we want to instantly rollback any changes by changing the traffic from the new release to the other server where the *'not faulty'* release is on.

Is there any term that describes this process?

I am trying to rollback any changes without any downtime.

Answer (score 3):

There are terms like

- [Blue-Green Deployment](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)
- and/or [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing)

that provide conceptual frameworks for running different releases/versions concurrently or in passive/active mode.

A big concern there is how you deal when application releases also require changes in for example a database schema and lots of other nitty-gritty details.

Comment: Yes, i am fimiliar with these terms, but when we encounter a critical bug later in time, it still takes releasetime until we see the old release being public. I want to instantly switch all the traffic to the old release as soon as we see a bug/error.

Comment: For that you have a traffic routing solution that directs users to either the blue or green environment. There are many approaches for that (like updating the CNAME record clients use (potentially dlow) to switching over a floating IP or using a load balancer)